# Socket.io disconnect error

Tags: ios, socket.io, disconnect

I'm using socket.io-obj library from https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc based on iOS7, but i found when the socket disconnect the server caused by the bad network environment, my application would be hang for a long time. 
Here is my code:

```
#define NOTE_CENTER [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
-(void)connectServer
{
    [socketIO connectToHost:SOCKETADDRESS
                     onPort:SOCKETPORT
                 withParams:nil
     ];
    status = Connecting;
    NSLog(@"%@",socketIO.debugDescription);
    [[] postNotificationName:kConnectingServer object:nil];
}

-(void)disConnectServer
{
    [socketIO disconnect];
}

-(BOOL)hasConnected {
    if (status==Connected) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
-(NetworkStatus)networkStatus
{
    return status;
}

-(void) sendEvent:(OrderEvent)eventIndex withData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    if (status==Connected) {
        [socketIO sendEvent:@"close" withData:data];
        //[socketIO sendEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",eventIndex] withData:data];
    }
}

-(void) sendEventWithName:(NSString*)eventName withData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    if (status==Connected) {
        [socketIO sendEvent:eventName withData:data];
    }
}
#pragma socketIO Delegate methods
- (void) socketIODidConnect:(SocketIO *)socket
{
    status = Connected;
    [NOTE_CENTER postNotificationName:kConnectedServer object:nil];
}

- (void) socketIODidDisconnect:(SocketIO *)socket disconnectedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    status = OffLine;
    NSLog(@"socket.io disconnected. did error occur? %@", error);
    [NOTE_CENTER postNotificationName:kDisConnectedServer object:nil];
}

- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket onError:(NSError *)error
{
    [socket  disconnectForced];
    [NOTE_CENTER postNotificationName:kConnecteServerError object:nil];
    if ([error code] == SocketIOUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"not authorized");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"onError() %@", error);
    }
}

- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveJSON:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
}

- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveEvent()");
    // test acknowledge
    NSString *packName = [packet name];
    //if (packet.name) {
    [NOTE_CENTER postNotificationName:packName object:nil userInfo:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[packet data],@"data", nil]];
    //}
    /*
    SocketIOCallback cb = ^(id argsData) {
        NSDictionary *response = argsData;
        // do something with response
        NSString *packetName = [response  stringValueForKey:@"name"];
        [NOTE_CENTER postNotificationName:packetName object:nil userInfo:response];
    };*/
}
```

Another problem i occurred is when i call "[socketIO disconnect]" , the server will not disconnect my application immediately. Please help me find the answer for these issue.

Big Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late response. I've find that if your socket.io server is down when trying to *disconnectForced*, the UI will block because, if you look at the method, the request is made using *sendSynchronousRequest*.

You can try modifying the method to use *sendAsynchronousRequest*, but I suggest further inspection of the class. You could also check the state of the connection before using *disconnectForced*.